# Backpropagation Through Time Recursive Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, machine-learning, neural-networks

Would it be plausible to write a recursive version of backpropagation through time for recurrent neural network training? I've only found the iterative version:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time

Comment: Is there a reason to care whether it is recursive or iterative?  Is there a motivation or context behind what drives you to ask this question?  I suspect the answer is going to be "sure, not that it makes any difference"; if that's the answer, is it going to answer your question?

Comment: The algorithm is recursive in nature, it's just implemented iteratively for reasons of efficiency. See if you can figure out how to write it recursively.